# How to insert new element to popped list?

Tags: python, list

```
shopping_list = ['food','drinks']

shopping_list.pop(0)

print(shopping_list)

new_shopping_list = shopping_list.pop(0)

new_shopping_list.insert(0,'fruits') 

print(new_shopping_list)
```

Hi this is my first question on stack overflow, have a feeling I am going to use this site a lot more in future :/. Just learnt about lists today, and I read that popped elements of a list can still be operated on despite being removed so I tested it out with the code above, but I had an attribute error pop up. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Here is the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'

Thanks in advance whoever answers :)

Comment: which programming language you are using to test your theory?

Comment: oh uh ..I am using python sorry I didnt put the tag there

Comment: what's the error you are getting? can you also add python tag to the question?

Comment: sure,  I just added the python tag and error in description

Comment: You are popping an item, assigning it to new_shopping_list, but this item is the string 'fruit' -- a str, not a list. Hence a 'str' does not have an 'insert' method like a 'list' does.

Comment: my intended behaviour is to add the 'fruits' into the list new_shopping_list. But shouldn't insert work on the list tho since its meant to move the items already in the list to the right?

Comment: ohh i defined it as the string, alright I understand now. ah yeah makes sense, hence the str error ok thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing string value in new_shopping_list. The new_shopping_list variable stores data which are pop from list not the whole list. You can use this snippet.

```
shopping_list = ['food','drinks']
shopping_list.pop(0)
print(shopping_list)
shopping_list.pop(0)
shopping_list.insert(0,'fruits')
print(shopping_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check type of new_shopping_list using `type(new_shopping_list)`. it is a `str`. It does not have any attribute 'insert'.
I think you wanted to insert in original list `shopping_list`

Answer (score 0):

It will continue easily without errors, if you delete

```
New_shopping_list=shopping_list.pop(0)
```

and write

```
Shopping_list.insert(0,'friuts')
Print(shopping_list)
```